# Pass docker directory as a maven parameter

Tags: maven, docker

I have a maven goal that requires the server home folder as a parameter.  On my local i just do:

```
mvn test -Dserverhome=/Users/foo/MyServer
```

On the test machine, the server is inside a docker container.  How do i point to my server directory that is inside a docker container?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [mount your host folder as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)

```
docker run -d -P --name aname -v /Users/foo/MyServer:/myserver yourImage
```

That way, your maven command can *always* be (within the container)

```
 mvn test -Dserverhome=/myserver
```

Because you trust that, at runtime, `/myserver` will have been associated with the right host folder.

Note that if you are using docker on Mac or Windows, `/Users` is already mounted (by VirtualBox and by boot2docker tinycore Linux), so you would not even need to declare the data volume.